# HELM(error) data: Too long: must have at most 1048576 bytes

Tags: kubernetes, helm

ok I have a huge applications with multiple components, each have plentyful config files

directory tree looks like this

```
# ls -1 .
Chart.yaml
configs
templates
values.yaml

# ls -1 configs
component1-config
component2-config
component3-config
component4-config

# ls -1 templates
component1.yaml
component2.yaml
component3.yaml
component4.yaml
_helpers.tpl
secrets.yaml
```

I am creating configmaps for multiple folders of each component like this

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-component1-folder1
  namespace: {{ .Values.nSpace }}
data:
{{ $currentScope := . }}
{{ range $path, $_ :=  .Files.Glob  "configs/component1/folder1/**" }}
{{- with $currentScope}}
  {{ (base $path) }}: |-
{{ .Files.Get $path | indent 6 }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-component1-folder2
  namespace: {{ .Values.nSpace }}
data:
{{ $currentScope := . }}
{{ range $path, $_ :=  .Files.Glob  "configs/component1/folder2/**" }}
{{- with $currentScope}}
  {{ (base $path) }}: |-
{{ .Files.Get $path | indent 6 }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

and some standard deployment & services also included
problem is when I run `helm install myapp .` it throws this `data too long error`
which I want to avoid, as my application may grow.

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: create: failed to create: Secret "sh.helm.release.v1.myapp.v1" is invalid: data: Too long: must have at most 1048576 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

files or folders (including hidden files and folders) in your chart cannot be larger (approximately) 1MB. You need to delete them or put them in the `.hemignore` file to exclude.
In my case, `.git` folder is bigger than 1MB and it is not needed, after deleting it, `helm install` works.

[image]

The same issue:
https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1996

Comment: Thank you, this was my fix. Love your profile picture ;) Big Swiftie here